# How to create a mathematical curve (probably just an image) in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, curves

Pretty much the title explains what I try to achieve.

Having a set of points in two dimensions, I want to create somehow the curve tha passes from all these points.
Whether it will be a graphical window with the mathematical curve or just a jpg produced, is of no importance.

Any help? Thx!

Comment: What OS ? And is this C or C++ ?

Comment: Are straight lines between adjacent points good enough, or do you want smooth curves (like splines)?

Comment: So you want to fit a curve to your data? What kind of curve? Plot the data, then fit an appropriate function to it using the least-squares method.

Comment: I whould like to be cross-platform. I don't really care if it will be C or C++ and I'd like them to be smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please refrain from tagging questions with C and C++, or using the term C/C++. C and C++ are two distinct, very different languages.

That being said, it seems you are looking for a way to *plot* data. There are different libraries allowing you to do that, among those are:

http://codecutter.org/tools/koolplot/

http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/

http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/

You can integrate those libraries into your application to produce plots of your data points. There are of course different, additional libraries, but these are the ones that came to my mind first.